# json decode of iphone json response in php

Tags: php, json

I am getting json response form iphone app as below

```
{"json":{"age":"23","userid":"1","weight":"55","fullname":"goutham"}};
```

can any one tell me how to decode it..

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP's function: [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode)

```
<?php
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

var_dump(json_decode($json));
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));

?>
```

Source: Example from the above referenced Manual

Answer (score 0):

Use json_decode

```
$array = json_decode($string, true);
/// please note the second parameter 'true' here, it is needed if you want your o/p as array or you will get it as object

print_r($array);
```

ref : http://php.net/json_decode

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
json_decode();
```

like

```
json_decode($my_json);
```

or you can use like json_code.age;json_code.userid like that
refer this http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

or you can refer this onlinr converter http://json.parser.online.fr/

Answer (score 0):

I think we are missing the question here, looking from the json string u have provided, you can clearly see that you have an object with its properties .

Have a look at the specs of json http://www.json.org/

{json:{age:23 etc

I would expect that by doing json_decode to it u would be able to get the object properties by simply saying : $json->age

Hope this helps